# The modifier "private" in not valid for this item c#

Tags: c#

I dont know what to do, im new to whole coding and the project im working on is going quite well, tried adding more commands and this problem jumps to the first private part here. If needed i can send the rest of the code

```
RegisterYNCommand();
{


}

private void RegisterYNCommand();
{
    {
        Commands.CreateCommand("YN")
            .Do(async (e) => 
            {
                int yesnoIndex = rand.Next(randomTexts.Length);
                string memeToPost = yesno[yesnoIndex];
                await e.Channel.SendMessage(memeToPost);
            });
```

Comment: Your method declarations have `;` before the body - that's incorrect.

Comment: I suspect there are other wrong things in the code. The `RegisterYNCommand();` call is inside a method? and `RegisterYNCommand()` declaration is also inside the same method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first

```
RegisterNYCommand(); 
{ 

}
```

Looks like duplicated code...

and the `;` at the end of

```
private void RegisterNYCommand(); // This ';'
{
     Commands.CreateCommand("YN")
        .Do(async (e) => 
        {
            int yesnoIndex = rand.Next(randomTexts.Length);
            string memeToPost = yesno[yesnoIndex];
            await e.Channel.SendMessage(memeToPost);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `;` character after your methods declaration:

```
 private void RegisterYNCommand()
 {
```

Comment: I already tried that, still doesn't work

Comment: Then you have to provide more details. Edit your question and provide text of error compiler gives you as well as appropriate lines of code concerning these errors.

Comment: You missed the problematic double declaration of the method, although pointed in the main problem, there were 2 problems.